# How can I link CSS and HTML in different folders?

Tags: html, css, filepath, external-links

I have a stylesheet named **style.css** which is located inside a folder named css

And a HTML file named **template.html** in a folder named html

Both the folders are inside a folder named WebSite ( I guess that's the root folder. I'm new to html )

I want to link style.css to template.html using relative path.

My folder structure :

```
WebSite
      |
      |--css
           |
           |--style.css
           |
      |--html
            |
            |--template.html
            |
      |--index.html
```

I tried using 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`

It didn't work

For more clarity I tried using view-source: before the url and clicked on the link but it showed

```
storage/emulated/0/WebSite/html/css/style.css (No such file or directory)
```

I am using Acode free app on Android mobile.

Comment: Did you tried using this: "~/css/style.css" ?

Comment: @Naveen K R why are you keeping template.html file inside html folder? Bring template.html file out of html folder and that will work

Comment: I'm trying to organize everything and keep everything in respective folders.

Answer (score 1):

I have misread what you were actually asking for my fault. First I would test out linking the css sheet with a test html document to see if its something to do with the app. I dont know how "view source" works in this case but the view source is saying that your css folder, thus your css sheet is inside your html folder and according to your diagram explaining your folders, that is not true. In that case then your style sheet link would be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">` An actual screenshot of your folder system , though not necessary, would be nice.

Comment: I didn't get you about index.html being it's own folder

Comment: I tried "../css/style.css" , "/css/style.css" , "~/css/style.css" and *../../css/style.css" nothing worked

Comment: After each change I used view-source: and clicked on the link and it shows:                                                        /storage/emulated/0/WebSite/html/~/css/style.css (No such file or directory)

Comment: your answer is true ... please edit answer and describe better than this.